# Is there a meaningful link between the golden ratio and chaos theory?

Tags: chaos-theory, golden-ratio

I heard it casually mentioned by strangers but am unable to find any information about this.

Is there a meaningful link between the golden ratio and chaos theory?

The closest thing I could find is this, which involves $\phi$, but seemingly not in a meaningful way. Other number sequences seem like they could have been used instead.

**Article:** [*"Fibonacci Chaos And Time's Arrow"*](https://www.science20.com/hammock_physicist/fibonacci_chaos_and_times_arrow?fbclid=IwAR0ybXEv0TaqTilWn5KNXbHcwFl7qugKeSkzfM9-mKi1Og7dTrtu55kKZPw)